# Regex to validate custom tracking information

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am working on a requirement to validate tracking information with the following restrictions:

Format: `COPYYYY#####`

`COP` is a fixed prefix of each tracking information

`YYYY` is a year in which the tracking information was submitted *(valid years: 2015-2018)*

`#####` is a randomly generated 5 digit number

Tracking information should only have 3 letter characters (COP prefix)

Tracking information should have exactly 9 numeric characters that follow the first 3 letter characters.

Tracking information should be exactly 12 characters long

---

Since regex is not great solution to validate number range, I decided to check year later once the format is valid.

`COP` followed by 9 digits (i.e `COPXXXXXXXXX`)

The regex below is always returning false, even for correct inputs.

```
/^COP\d{9}$/
```

Please suggest corrections to above regex and also share thoughts on validating year range in regex (if it is cleaner approach).

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Also please fix your tags. Is it java or javascript?

Comment: The regex with the years could be `^COP201[5-8]\d{5}$` but `^COP\d{9}$` would also match when there are 9 digits. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern `\bCOP(201[5-8])(\d{5})\b`

---

Test source code (JavaScript):

```
var re = /\bCOP(201[5-8])(\d{5})\b/g;
var s = 'To track your packages, enter COP201812345 and COP201867890 at www.example.org';
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        var e = document.createElement('div');
        e.innerHTML = 'Match: ' + m[0] + ' (Year: ' + m[1] + ', Id: ' + m[2] + ')';
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(e);
    }
} while (m);
```

Test source code (Java):

```
String s = "To track your packages, enter COP201812345 and COP201867890 at www.example.org";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bCOP(201[5-8])(\\d{5})\\b").matcher(s);
 
while (m.find()) 
    System.out.println(
        "Match: " + m.group() + 
        " (Year: " + m.group(1) + ", Id: " + m.group(2) + ")");
}
```

Output:

> Match: COP201812345 (Year: 2018, Id: 12345)
>
> Match: COP201867890 (Year: 2018, Id: 67890)

---

Test it **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/65ax320q/)** (JavaScript) and **[here](https://ideone.com/oRjGI2)** (Java).

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below.

```java
String value = "COP201812345";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(COP)(201[5-8])(\\d{5})$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Tracking number " + value + " is valid");
    System.out.println("Tracking prefix: "               + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Year between 2015 and 2018 is: " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("Random 5 digit number is: "      + m.group(3));
}
else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

Output:

> Tracking number COP201812345 is valid
>
> Tracking prefix: COP
>
> Year between 2015 and 2018 is: 2018
>
> Random 5 digit number is: 12345